# How to call a parent app's helper method from a rails 3.1 engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-engines

I'm building a rails engine that uses the "acts as" format to establish relationships with the parent application's User model.

```
module Cornerstone

  module ActsAsCornerstoneUser

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods

      def acts_as_cornerstone_user(options = {})

        #= Associations
        has_many :cornerstone_discussions


        #= Options
        Cornerstone::Config.auth_with << options[:auth_with] if options[:auth_with]
        Cornerstone::Config.auth_with.flatten!

      end
    end

    module InstanceMethods

    end

  end

  ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ActsAsCornerstoneUser

end
```

I would like for a developer to be able to specify a helper method name using the `:auth_with` option.  The idea is that the developer will specify a helper method in the parent application that will return the signed in user for that session.

My question is once the developer has specified the `auth_with` option, how can I call that parent application's method??

Is there a better approach to obtaining the parent application's signed in user?  I'd like it to be as flexible as possible such that it is not dependent on simply calling `current_user`.

Comment: Do you need one or many cornerstone users? (ie. one auth method or one per class)

Comment: Also, the authentication should be the job of a controller. Where will you need the authenticated user?

Comment: The authenticated user will be needed within the engine's own controllers, but authentication occurs in the parent application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work, as long as you have only one cornerstone user defined in your application :

```rb
module Cornerstone
  module ActsAsCornerstoneUser
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def acts_as_cornerstone_user(options = {})

        #= Associations
        has_many :cornerstone_discussions

        #= Options
        Cornerstone::Config.auth_with = options[:auth_with] if options[:auth_with]
      end
    end

    module InstanceMethods

    end

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(ClassMethods)
      base.include(InstanceMethods)
    end
  end

  ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ActsAsCornerstoneUser
end
```

Then define a helper in your gem (ie. in `app/helpers/cornerstone_helper.rb`) :

```rb
module Cornerstone
  module CornerStoneHelper
    def current_cornerstone_user
      Config.auth_with.call(controller)
    end
  end
end
```

The `acts_as_cornerstone` method is the used like this :

```rb
class MyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_cornerstone_user :auth_with => Proc.new { |controller| controller.current_user }
end
```

You can then use the `current_cornerstone_user` helper to get the current authenticated user.

This method breaks when `acts_as_cornerstone_user` is used on multiple classes. But you then have the problem of having multiple cornerstone users without knowing anything about the application models (you're supposed to be in your gem).

**Update**

If you'd like to have a syntax like `:auth_with => :warden`, you could replace the helper with the following :

```rb
module Cornerstone
  module CornerStoneHelper
    def current_cornerstone_user
      if Config.auth_with.respond_to?(:call)
        Config.auth_with.call(controller)
      elsif Config::AUTH_MODES.keys.include?(Config.auth_with)
        Config::AUTH_MODES[Config.auth_with].call(controller)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

with `Cornerstone::Config::AUTH_MODES` set up like this :

```rb
module Cornerstone
  class Config
    AUTH_MODES = {
      :warden => Proc.new { |controller| controller.env['warden'].user },
      :devise => Proc.new { |controller| controller.current_user }
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try this out, but what would happen if there are multiple user classes I wonder?  For example, an Admin class that inherits from a User class or something like that... I'm trying to make the engine as flexible as possible.  Calling a current_user method that is defined within the parent application is the best method I could come up with.  Ideally, I'd like to use something like what you outlined above PLUS :auth_with => :warden.  The warden case is much easier.

Comment: I just found some time to try out your solutions.  Unfortunately, I don't think specifying the Proc within the model will work because the model does not have access to a controller object.  The source is on github if you'd like to take a closer look... https://github.com/astjohn/cornerstone

Comment: The model doesn't have to know about the controller. It's only defining a Proc that accepts a controller as its first parameter. The controller comes from the helper method (when executing Config.auth_with.call(controller)).