# Authentication and authorization in a Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-engines

I'm trying to extract a blog model and controller out of a Rails app. I have a Rails Engine called `Blog` and I'm going to mount it on the `/blog` route of the main app.

In my `Blog` engine I have a `PostsController` which has normal CRUD actions. The problem is that I want to use the authentication methods from the main rails app.

```
# app/controllers/blog/posts_controller.rb
module Blog
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
    # Basically I want to have access to the require_login method
    # from the main app.
    before_filter :require_login, only: [:new, :create]

    def new
      @post = Post.new
      authorize! :create, Post
    end
  end
end
```

And I need access to the User model so that I can check for CanCan abilities for authorizations. For example, only admins are allowed to create blog posts.

```
# app/models/blog/ability.rb
module Blog
  class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new

      # The user.admin? method is defined on the User class
      # from the main rails app.
      if user.admin?
        can [:create, :update], Post
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way to accomplish these things?

Comment: Look how I solved similar problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668874/how-get-devises-current-user-method-in-rails-engine

Comment: or this one 2, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845747/how-to-call-a-parent-apps-helper-method-from-a-rails-3-1-engine

Comment: @wildDAlex or westonplatter - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answers from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> Look how I solved similar problem - [How get Devise's current_user method in Rails Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668874/how-get-devises-current-user-method-in-rails-engine)

~ answer per [wildDAlex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/834851/wilddalex)

> or this one 2, [How to call a parent app's helper method from a rails 3.1 engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845747/how-to-call-a-parent-apps-helper-method-from-a-rails-3-1-engine)

~ answer per [westonplatter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665578/westonplatter)