# How get Devise's current_user method in Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-engines

I have a Rails application that's using the Devise gem, and I'm creating a Rails Engine to mount in this app.

```
mount Comments::Engine => '/talk', :as => 'comments'
```

Within the Engine, I want to get the `current_user` instance from main application.

In **{main_app}/initializers/comments.rb**

```
Comments.user_class = "User"
Comments.current_user = "current_user" #current_user is Devise method(works fine in app)
```

In **{engine}/lib/comments.rb**

```
require "comments/engine"

module Comments
  mattr_accessor :user_class, :current_user

  def self.user_class
    @@user_class.constantize
  end

  def self.current_user
    send(@@current_user)
  end
end
```

When I call `Comments.current_user`, I get the error "wrong constant name current_user".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Seams I'm solved problem. 
I'd call current_user within Comments model and it didn't work. 
However getting `current_user` from controller, works fine. 
But this is not elegant way (.

Comment: current_user uses the session, so it is not supposed to work on the model.