# Accessing devise current_user inside another rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-engines

So here is my issue. I have a main application which has devise in it,for which I am creating an engine. In the engine I need the current_user from main app. Not sure how I will get that, I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668874/how-get-devises-current-user-method-in-rails-engine) but to no avail. Any help would be great. If this is not recommended please do explain why.

Answer (score 3):

**Solved it**

In the engine you can access the main app using 'main_app'. In this variable you have access to the current user, assuming you have devise. In order to access devise current_user all you have to do is

```
main_app.scope.env['warden'].user
```

Devise stores the user inside warden key in the session. Since it uses warden internally to authenticate and store the details in session.

If there is an alternative solution please do let me know.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Rails 5.1+ this would instead be

`main_app.scope.request.env['warden'].user`

Thats because env has been deprecated.