# Converting rails app to engine: calling associations using namespacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm having a stab at converting https://github.com/ari/jobsworth to an engine (which I'm calling `scheduler` for the moment). One of the things to do is to set up associations between the main app's `User` and models in the engine.

I'm using `acts_as_scheduler_user` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845747/how-to-call-a-parent-apps-helper-method-from-a-rails-3-1-engine):

```
require "scheduler/engine"

module Scheduler    

module ActsAsSchedulerUser

   module ClassMethods

       def acts_as_scheduler_user(options = {})   
           has_many    :widgets
       end
#etc
```

The nascent engine is hooked up to my main app, and when I call `User.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)` in either the the engine's code or the main app's code I successfully get

```
#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x000001069e45b0 @macro=:has_many, @name=:widgets, @options={:order=>"widgets.column, widgets.position", :dependent=>:destroy, :extend=>[]}, @active_record=User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, confirmation_token: string, confirmed_at: datetime, confirmation_sent_at: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, first_name: string, last_name: string, client_id: integer, invitation_token: string, invitation_sent_at: datetime, invitation_accepted_at: datetime, invitation_limit: integer, invited_by_id: integer, invited_by_type: string, client_name_requested: string, mode: string, forem_admin: boolean, forem_state: string, forem_auto_subscribe: boolean), @plural_name="widgets", @collection=true>
```

And `current_user` is working fine in the engine app - returning the main app's current_user.

However when I call `current_user.widgets` in the engine's app I get the error `uninitialized constant User::Widget`.

Any thoughts?

++++++++++

EDIT: Ah, when I do `Widget.all` in the console I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Widget`, but when I do `Scheduler::Widget.all` I get the right response. So my question now is how do I call `current_user.widgets` whilst using namespacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing the point (not much experience with engines) but perhaps just pass the `has_many` class method the actual class to include namespacing.

```
def acts_as_scheduler_user(options = {})   
  has_many :widgets, :class_name => Scheduler::Widget
end
```

Comment: That should be `:class_name => `